# Why are the eventHandlers for ListenerContainerIdleEvent is not getting called?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have configured 2 listeners in my app config.

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactoryForReceiveEvent() {
    Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProps();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<server 1>");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactoryForPutawayEvent() {
    Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProps();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<server 2>");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForReceiveEvent() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryForReceiveEvent());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(Long.valueOf(30000L);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForPutawayEvent() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryForPutawayEvent());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(30000L);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}
```

In order to get my app to start I had to turn off kafka auto config. When messages are posted, they are getting read so I am sure that the 2 listeners are working. However when no messages are posted, the eventHandlers for ListenerContainerIdleEvent are not getting called. What could be preventing these eventHandlers from being called?

```
@EventListener
public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    LOG.info("No messages received for " + event.getIdleTime() + " milliseconds");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just met this issue, and I believe the reason for none of the events being fired in the original code was the following:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java, which publishes only a fraction of application events (does not publish the "ListenerContainerIdleEvent" event).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java publishes these events.

Using @KafkaListener defaults to KafkaMessageListenerContainer, which is why those events worked in Gary's example.

Comment: ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer uses a bunch of KafkaMessageListenercontainers. So shouldn't one of those emit this event?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? Where is your event listener defined? I just tested it with 2.1.5 and everything works fine...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49889974Application {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(So49889974Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49889974Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(30000L);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
        return factory;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id="foo", topics = "so49889974")
    public void listen(String in) {

    }

    @EventListener
    public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        logger.info(event);
    }

}
```

and

```
2018-04-18 10:39:04.238  INFO 92080 --- [      foo-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so49889974-0]
2018-04-18 10:39:31.339  INFO 92080 --- [      foo-0-C-1] com.example.So49889974Application        : ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=30.242s, listenerId=foo-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=foo-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[so49889974-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[so49889974-0]]
2018-04-18 10:40:01.451  INFO 92080 --- [      foo-0-C-1] com.example.So49889974Application        : ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=60.354s, listenerId=foo-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=foo-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[so49889974-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[so49889974-0]]
```

Comment: I took out the second listener and container, then I switched back to auto configure and started getting the events. I removed auto config and added back the listener + container...one at a time...and this time it worked! So I am not sure why these events were not getting called. After all the tweaks, the code was the same as I pasted above...strange! I am using 2.0.1 version.